# Jquery select2 error while taking json data

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-select2

I'm using jquery Select2 4.1.0-rc.0
This is my Javascitp code:

```
        $('#task_dname').select2({
        placeholder: 'Select an item',
//      tags: true,
//      cache: true,
        delay: 250,
        maximumInputLength: 20,
        minimumInputLength: 2,
        dataType: 'json',
        ajax: {
            type: 'post',
            url: 'query_list_tasks.php',
            data: function (params) {var post_data = {searching: params.term, query: 'task_list'}; return post_data;},
            processResults: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            return {
              results: data.items
            };
          }
        }
      });;
```

PHP generating json:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $response[] =  array(
      "id" => $row['id'],
      "text" => $row['text']
   );
}

//echo json_encode($response);
echo '{ "results": '.json_encode($response).'}';
```

Json for processResults data (console.log):

```
{ "results": [{"id":"10","text":"Test1"},{"id":"11","text":"Test2"}]}
```

This seems ok but i get this error when i try to search something, and there is no options in select field showing up:

```
jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice') TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice')
```

Something is missing or im just to stupid? I'm. stuck.

Comment: return {
              results: data.items
            };
I think there is no items object in data

Comment: i've change { results: data.items } to { results: JSON.parse(data)}, console shows i get array but now also get error:

jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: t.slice is not a function TypeError: t.slice is not a function

Comment: return {
              results: data.results
            }; try like this

Comment: @Yasas Naveen
thx, but didnt work.

changed: 
return {results: JSON.parse(data)};

Comment: also PHP code need to be changed. 
this didnt work:
`echo '{ "results": '.json_encode($response).'}';`
this worked:
 `echo json_encode($response);`